# LINQPad + IQ Driver for MySQL Connection Error: Bad handshake

Tags: mysql, linqpad

I can't connect to my local MySQL Server with Linqpad + IQ Driver. I constantly get the following error:

**Connection Error: Bad handshake**

The MySQL Service is up and running. I can connect with command line client.

- MySQL Version: 5.5.15
- LINQPad Version: 4.31
- IQ Driver Version: 2.0.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out almost all possible (really!!!) different configurations and MySQL packages. The newest release that works is **MySQL Server 5.1.56**

I didn't find that particular release on mysql.com. But you can get it from here: http://olex.openlogic.com/packages/mysql/5.1.56